# building client-server windows application

Tags: c#, mysql, client-server

am trying yo build a client-server application using :

c# , MySql Server

the idea is < i have two PCs (clients) are connected to another PC (server)

as shown here : [image]

my questions :

1. how to show live data in both clients when one change a table ,  the view will changed at the another PC
2. how to build a method to manage clients' access to shared resources (db) to prevent errors -

   edit : i don't need a source code , just i need path to walk through to cross the road

Comment: That is a really hard question since you don't tell what _kind_ of server you intend to build. Getting change notifications from a WCF service works totally different from getting change notifications on a raw TCP connection (kind of, since under the hood the service callback uses the same technology, but with a few more abstraction layers in between), for example.

Comment: just updated my question

Comment: the connection will be tcp , it;s very simple system , 3 pcs in same lan

Answer (score 1):

There are two broad approaches to choose from.

1) Have each client periodically poll the server for updates.  Not recommended but easy to implement.
2) Have the server notify the clients of changes.  Much more efficient but can be tricky to implement.

Answer (score 1):

To notify clients about changes from other client you should do the following:

1. Aside from your connection threads you should store references to all currently connected clients, in some kind of synchronized collection (to make sure there are no race conditions).
2. Now, if any client commits any changes, the server iterates over the other clients and notifies each of them about the change, either with a "Entity X has changed, you should load it again" message or by just pushing the updated entity to the client, hoping that the client will react accordingly.
3. If you use the first approach, the client now has the choice of either loading the updated entity or load it when it is accessed the next time. The second approach will enforce the client to cache the data (or not, since the client may just cache the ID and reload the entity at another time as if the server just notified it about the update, like in the first approach).

If you can (for whatever reason) not trust the concurrent access safety of your database, you should employ something like a single threaded task queue (in the simplest case... There are more optimized approaches, which allow parallel read actions and prioritizing and such, but implementing that is *really* a pain).

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to consider a middle tier that interacts with a both the clients and the DB (ASP?,COM?,Custom Built?).  Otherwise, the individual clients will most likely need timers to check the last time the DB was updated.

AFA the sharing issue, it is a database.  Databases are designed for concurrent access, so.... not sure about the error part.  I you are using c#, and really worried about, ADO.NET has "pesimistic" mode to connect to the DB, but at the cost of performance.